# Regarding unmodifiable collection

Tags: java, collections

Consider the following code below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> intList2;
        intList1.add(1);
        intList1.add(2);
        intList1.add(3);
        intList2=Collections.unmodifiableList(intList1);
        intList1.add(4);

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(intList2.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

The result of the above code is

```
1
2
3
4
```

In the above code we create an *unmodifiable* `List intList2` from the contents of the `List intList`1. But after the `Collections.unmodifiable` statement when I make a change to `intList1` that change reflects to `intList2`. How is this possible ?

Comment: You cannot do `intList2.add()`. That does not mean you cannot do `intList1.add()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the [Javadoc for `Collections.unmodifiableList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29)

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list.

This means that the returned *view* is unmodifiable. If you have the original reference you can change the collection. If you change the collection then changes will be reflected in the view.

This has the advantage of being very fast, i.e. you don't need to copy the collection, but the disadvantage that you noted - the resulting collection is a view.

In order to create a truly unmodifiable collection you would need to copy *then* wrap:

```
intList2=Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(intList1));
```

This copies the contents of `intList1` into another collection then wraps that collection in the unmodifiable variable. No reference to the wrapped collection exists.

This is **expensive** - the entire underlying datastore (an array in this case) needs to duplicated which (generally) takes `O(n)`.

[Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) provides [immutable collections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) which solve some of the problems of making defensive copies:

- If a collection is already immutable it is not copied again
- Provide an interface which can be used to explicitly state that a collection is immutable
- Provide numerous static factory methods to generate immutable collections

But speed is still the key concern when using immutable copies of collections rather than unmodifiable views.

It should be noted that the usual use for `Collections.unmodifiableXXX` is to return from a method, for example a getter:

```
public Collection<Thing> getThings() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(things);
}
```

In this case there are two things to note:

1. The user of `getThings` cannot access `things` so the unmodifiability cannot be broken.
2. It would be very expensive to copy `things` each time a getter were called.

In summary the answer to your question is a little more complex than you might have expected and there are a number of aspects to consider when passing collections around in your application.

Comment: @harrypotter looking at your profile you seem to have asked several questions but not [accepted any answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work); please fix this.

Answer (score 1):

From the Javadoc of Collections.unmodifiableList:

> Returns an unmodifiable view of the specified list. This method allows modules to provide users with "read-only" access to internal lists.

It prevent the returned list to be modified, but the original list itself still can be.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are

```
 intList2=Collections.unmodifiableList(intList1);
```

creating unmodifiableList in intList2. So you are free to make changes in inList1
but you are not allowed to do any changes in intList2

try this:
     intList2.add(4);
you will get

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Unknown Source)
```

above exception.

Answer (score 1):

Collections.unmodifiableList returns a "read-only" view of the internal list. While the object that was returned is not modifiable the original list that it references can be modified.  Both objects point to the same object in memory so it will reflect changes made.

[Here](http://www.javacreed.com/modifying-an-unmodifiable-list/) is a good explanation of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the unmodifiable list is internally backed for the first list, if you really want it to be unmodifiable you shouldn't use the first List any more.